# How to sync states across all instances of a react web app

Tags: reactjs

So I made a tic tac toe game using react but now I want the states to sync across all instance of the web app so that 2 people can play the game remotely. How can I do that? do I have to use a database?

Couldnt find a good answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for live updates.

If you're just starting out you can just keep the game state in-memory on the server. After that you can try out SQLite and PostgreSQL.

For real games, scaling the number of connections and the game save strategy can get more complex, but for a hobby Tic Tac Toe project you should be OK with whatever.